# How to combine multiple columns in a csv and sort and unique values in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file and would like to combine 3 columns into 1 single column or row and only gets the unique values and add @gmail.com to see each of the field.

How can i do it python3 ?

Comment: Here is my script

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python3

import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   first_row = next(reader, None)
   rows = list(reader)
   for row in rows:
      with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
         writer = csv.writer(g)
         for row in reader:
           items = [' '.join([row[7], row[9], row[-1]])]
           unique = []
           for item in items:
              if item not in unique:
                  writer.writerow(item)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your script; don't post it in a comment.

Comment: By the way, csv.DictReader is typically much easier to deal with: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file1, 'a') as output:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(output)
            csv_writer.writerow(first_row)
            # collect emailids
            custids = []
            for row in rows:
                if corpid in row:
                    custids.append(row[7])
                    custids.append(row[9])
                    custids.append(row[-1])
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
        ids = list(filter(None,custids))
        uniqids = list(dict.fromkeys(ids))
        emailids = []
        for x in uniqids:
            emailids.append(x + "@gmail.com")
        emailids = ';'.join(emailids)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).